# How to add edge labels in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to draw a graph using Graphviz, but I need to add labels on the edges. There does not seem to be any way to that in Graphviz. 
Are there a way out?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

You use the [label property](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:label) attached to the edge.

```
digraph G {
 a -> b [ label="a to b" ];
 b -> c [ label="another label"];
}
```

The above generates a graph that looks something like this.

[image]

Comment: Why are the labels touching the edges? Shouldn't there be a gap?

Comment: @AndreKR A quick fix is to just put a space at the beginning of the label: a -> b [ label=" a to b" ];

Comment: This duplicates the definitions a lot. Is there a way to do something like that: `a - "a to b" > b - "b to c" > c` ?

Comment: Another fix is to use `rankdir="LR";`, which produces a horizontal graph with labels placed above the edge without touching.

Comment: is there a way to have the labels rotated vertically to go paralle to the line?

Comment: I don't believe there's any need to declare a b or c before describing edges, is there?

Comment: @Potherca Ha! Cool, I suppose, typically shouldn't edit other people's code, but in this case, probably fine. Good job, cheers!

Comment: Regarding the labels touching the edges...the work-arounds mentioned seem a little ad-hoc, and also rely on axis aligned graph edges. Labels seem often to touch the edges with complex graphs. Is there no general solution?

Comment: For future reference, the DOT language documentation is [here](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) and the attributes documentation is [here](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html).

Comment: I wish the syntax was more like `graph-easy`: https://github.com/ironcamel/Graph-Easy/wiki#hello-world

Comment: Should we replace `weight` with `label` than?

Answer (score 41):

@Andrew Walker has given a great answer!

It's also worth being aware of the `labeltooltip` [attribute](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labeltooltip).  This allows an additional string to be attached to the label of an edge.  This is easier for a user than the `tooltip` attribute, as it can be fiddly to hover directly on an edge.  The syntax is as follows:

```
digraph G {
 a -> b [label="  a to b" labeltooltip="this is a tooltip"];
 b -> c [label="  another label" ];
}
```

Which gives the following result:
[image: example of a label with tooltip]

Comment: Tooltip hint invaluable. Thanks.

Comment: Which version did you try with? With version dot - graphviz version 2.43.0 (0) tooltip does not show up.

Answer (score 26):

Landed here by googling whether labels could be on arrow's ends, for UML's composition/aggregation. The answer is yes:

`"Person" -> "Hand"  [headlabel="*", taillabel="1"]`

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can use `label="\E"` It will generate bye default label.

**For Example:**

```
digraph G {
 a -> b [ label="\E" ];
 b -> c [ label="\E"];
}
```