# Graphviz default label for edge

Tags: python, graphviz

I am making graph using graph. Is there any way I can get default edge label ?

```
digraph G {
 a -> b [label="a -> b" ];
 b -> c [label=" b ->" ];
}
```

I want to get label default not manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the Graphviz Document. 
Also I gave same kind of questions answer.

You can look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806870/how-to-add-edge-labels-in-graphviz/50591070#50591070)

If you can not get solution from my answer you can do comment here..