# Set distance between arrow and label

Tags: dot

I have this little example code:

```
digraph Test {
    Beginning -> Ending [label="What", labeldistance=2.0];
}
```

This gives me this structure:

[image]

If I remove the `labeldistance=2.0`, than I'm getting the same graph. How can increase the distance of the label `What` to the arrow so it's a little bit moved to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806870/how-to-add-edge-labels-in-graphviz) answer which explains amongst other thinks that you just need to add spaces in front of your label... like this:

```
digraph Test {
    Beginning -> Ending [label=" What", labeldistance=2.0];
}
```

and produces this:

[image]

Also, [`labeldistance`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labeldistance) works only on the `headlabel` and `taillabel` as you can read in the docs.

Comment: why is `labeldistance=2.0` same as `labeldistance=10.0`?